On a theorem by Iwaniec about binary quadratic polynomials representing infinitely many primes
In Theorem 1.1 (i) of http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa24/aa2451.pdf, Iwaniec showed that a certain type of quadratic polynomial $P(x,y)$ represents infinitely many primes, where $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$. 
Is there any simple argument showing that $P(x,y)$ also represents infinitely many primes, where $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}_+^2$?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075/

Do you mean "quadratic form" or "quadratic polynomial"? That an irreducible, primitive binary quadratic form represents infinitely many primes is well-known. The point of his paper is to treat arbitrary quadratic polynomials $f$ which are generically geometrically irreducible (unlike forms).
